# Fullscreen Background Video with HTML5

Tags: html, video, background, fullscreen, html5-video

i'm trying to create a website with a full screen background video, so I searched several sites on Google and some posts on StrackoverFlow. The most interesting post was that about the http://www.html5-fullscreen-video.com, however I can not get it to work.

Does anybody has an working source code that succesfully launches fullscreen background video for desktop and tablet?

Cheers,
Sebastian

Comment: Anybody some more tips? 

http://www.ycoyacht.com/ looks very nice, only does not work on tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this really good tutorial: https://dev.opera.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2/

your videotag should look like

```
 <video poster="movie.jpg" controls>
   <source src='movie.webm' type='video/webm'/>
   <source src='movie.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>
   <source src='movie.mp4' type='video/mp4'/>
   <p>Your browser doesn t support html5.</p>
 </video>
```

poster is your thumbnail, and source are the different sources for the different browsers.

You might register your videotypes at your server using .htaccess-file like:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Comment: you re welcome. and for the future: you can only accept one answer per question! if you find other comments useful, you can upvote them while clicking at the arrows above number left side.

Answer (score 0):

there are two things you need to take care of:

1.your video-element has to fit the hole screen f.e. with css via

```
 .videotag{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
 }  
 //should work, if not add position:absolute; left: 0px; top:0px;
```

2.be sure, that your video tag is always in the background and doesn t overlay any html content. you can solve this with the z-index. higher numbers lie above lower z-index numbers.

```
 .videotag{
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 .contentToOverlayVideo{
   z-index: 5;
 }
```

Comment: Hello,

thank you for the comment, how do I need to place the video on the website? The YCOYacht website uses something likes this:


<div class="homepage-video"
             data-video-h264="http://m.ycoyacht.com/video/h264/yco_audio.mp4"
             data-video-webm="http://m.ycoyacht.com/video/webm/yco_audio.webm"
             data-video-ogv="http://m.ycoyacht.com/video/ogg/yco_audio.ogv"
             data-video-poster="http://m.ycoyacht.com/video/poster/yco_1.png">
</div>